# add all checkbox values to array

Tags: php, arrays

My html code :

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="user1" value="user1"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
    <input id="user2" value="user2"  name="invite[]" type="checkbox">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code is :

```
if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
    if (is_array($_POST['invite'])) {
        foreach($_POST['invite'] as $value){
            $list = array($value);
            $fh = print_r($list, true);
        }
    } 
}
```

And the print_r output is :

```
Array ( [0] => user1 ) 
Array ( [0] => user2 )
```

My required output is: Array ( [0] => user1  [1] => user2 )

I'm working from the last 36 hours and googled but no luck. What is the error in my code or is there any better way to achieve checkbox values into an array(the actual values in my code are email id"s)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST['invite']);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['invite']` already is `Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 )`. What you're doing is looping through it then putting the value (e.g. `user1`) into a new array.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['invite'])) {
    foreach($_POST['invite'] as $value){
         $list = $_POST['invite'];
output is : Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 ) 
Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 )
 
$fh = print_r($list, true);

echo "<br/>". $fh;

    }
  } 
}

Comment: But still i'm getting Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 ) 
Array ( [0] => user1 [1] => user2 )

Comment: @user2430278 I don't mind this harshly, but you need to read up on the basics of PHP. In a foreach loop, your provide your array (in this case `$_POST['invite']`) then you tell it what variable to hold each array indexes value in. In your case, you've said to put it into `$value`, so `$value` contains `user1` and `user2`.

Comment: Done Working.. Thank you (@Prisoner)